# How to compare rows for differences in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with DocNum, DocVer, ClientNum, MatterNum. Some docs have versions with different ClientNum/MatterNum combinations and I need to create a report with that information.

1 - I've created a table with DocNum, DocVer, ClientNum, MatterNum where the version is > 1 since only docs with more than a single version are possibly affected.

2 - I'm trying to figure out how best to compare all versions 2+ to the version 1 for a specific doc and denote what doesn't match. (Group By DocNum, ClientNum, MatterNum, or Join, Etc.)

I would like a NULL to denote any version 2+ that don't match the ClientNum and MatterNum of the first version.

Sample Table Data:

```
docnum, version, client, matter    
351,    1,       15000,  00010    
351,    2,       15000,  00020
```

The desired output would be a column that denotes docnums and versions that do not match the version 1.

```
docnum, version, client, matter, matched 

351,    1,       15000,  00010, y  

351,    2,       15000,  00020, n
```

Comment: When asking a question to the community, please provide as much informaiton about the issue as possible. For example you are stating that you have created a table, please let us see this table and some sample data. In addition to thi splease also provide the desired output. This approach will deter other members form downvoting as you have provided a decent amount of informaiton to work with.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Did the additional data help?

Comment: @jimmy8ball Did the additional data help?

Comment: As other explain you need provide a desire output so we can build a query for that.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'll make sure I do that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can join your new table that has only version 2+ records back to the original table's version 1 record. Using `case` you can check if they match and display null if they don't.

```
SELECT 
    yt.DocNum
  , yt.DocVer
  , CASE WHEN yt.ClientNum <> ot.ClientNum THEN NULL ELSE yt.ClientNum END AS 'ClientNum'
  , CASE WHEN yt.NatterNum <> ot.MatterNum THEN NULL ELSE yt.MatterNum END AS 'MatterNum'
FROM YourTable yt -- table with versions 2+
JOIN OriginalTable ot 
  ON yt.DocNum = ot.DocuNum AND ot.DocVer = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @SQLChao I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a self join based on the version number and test the matter column for a change in value, You'll get the idea:

```
 declare @test table (docnum int, version int, client nvarchar(10), matter nvarchar(10));
 insert into @test
 values
 (351, 1, '15000', '00010'),
 (351, 2, '15000', '00020')

 -- assumes your version increases sequentially
 select t1.docnum, t1.matter, t2.matter, case when t1.matter <> t2.matter then 'flag' else 'ok' end [flag]
 from @test t1
 left join @test t2
 on t1.client = t2.client
 and t1.docnum = t2.docnum
 and t1.version = t2.version - 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly!